# <Column 'user_address' cannot be null> Spring boot mysql insert problem

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, insert

I study java/spring-boot 1 weeks ago. And now, I want insert data in database. But I couldn't insert data.

what should i do?

UserVO.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user_tbl")
@NonNull
public class UserVO {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idx", nullable = false, length = 5)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idx;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 30, updatable = false)
    private String user_id;

    @Column(name = "user_pw", nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String user_pw;

    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String user_name;

    @Column(name = "user_gender", nullable = false, length = 1)
    private String user_gender;

    @Column(name = "user_email", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    private String user_email;

    @Column(name = "user_address", nullable = false, length = 2000)
    private String user_address;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date create_date;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_date", nullable = false)
    private Date update_date;

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserVO, Long> {

}
```

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String addUser(UserVO userAdd) {
    UserVO userVO = userRepository.save(userAdd);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Table Name = 'user_tbl' / Using DataBase = MySQL
Table Column

```
idx              int(11)      not null     primary key,
created_date     datetime     not null,
updated_date     datetime     not null,
user_address     varchar(100) not null,
user_email       varchar(50)  not null     UNIQUE,
user_gender      varchar(1)   not null,
user_id          varchar(30)  not null     UNIQUE,
user_name        varchar(12)  not null,
user_pw          varchar(25)  not null
```

Insert Data(Using Postman, Type = JSON)

```
{
    "created_date": "2019-09-18 00:00:00",
    "updated_date": "2019-09-18 00:00:00",
    "user_address": "Earth",
    "user_email": "admin@admin.com",
    "user_gender": "1",
    "user_id": "SubAdmin",
    "user_name": "admin",
    "user_pw": "0000"
}
```

Spring-Boot-Console-Error

```
Hibernate: insert into user_tbl (created_date, updated_date, user_address, user_email, user_gender, user_id, user_name, user_pw) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN 7472 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000<br/>
ERROR 7472 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'user_address' cannot be null
ERROR 7472 --- [nio-8090-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_address' cannot be null
...
```

Postman error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-09-17T02:44:06.369+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/user_add"
}
```

Why is user_address null instead of 'Earth'?

Comment: Please enable hibernate trace and see what all values hibernate is setting for each column.

loggin.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
loggin.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

Comment: console.log : binding parameter [3~8] as [VARCHAR] - [null]

Comment: Seems like an issue with serialization, please print VO on controller method.

Comment: Why use @JsonProperty?

Comment: why is it displaying two lengths , in VO length = 2000 and  in table description its varchar(100)

Answer (score -1):

In your controller class please add **@RequestBody** annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user_add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String addUser(@RequestBody UserVO userAdd) {
UserVO userVO = userRepository.save(userAdd);
return "redirect:/";
}
```